# How to make list value column mapping to another column?

Tags: sql

[image]

I wonder how to make `table3` using `table1` and `table2`.

I don't know how to map `name_list` in table to `name` in table1.

Is it possible using `SQL` only?

Comment: Never, ever store data as comma separated item. It will only cause you lots of problems! One value per row is the golden rule!

Answer (score 0):

following code work in `Sql Server`

```
SELECT name_list,STRING_AGG(gender,',') AS gender_list
    FROM
     (SELECT s.info, f.value as name,name_list
      FROM table2 AS s
      CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s.name_list, ',') AS f) t1
    
  JOIN table1 t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
    
  GROUP BY name_list
```